# JPA data relationships and JSON deserialization

Tags: json, orm, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I've built an application backend using Spring-Data-JPA on top of MySQL and I am exposing these repositories to the world using Jackson (JSON) and custom services.

Slightly simplified, the datamodel consists of of merchants, transactions and customers and associations between them. In the database a transaction has a merchant_id and a customer_id.

I don't want to send a complete copy of the merchant for each record, so for reads I have exposed the id's using Jackson's concept of views:

```
@JsonView(Views.Partner.class)
@Column(name = "merchant_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long merchantId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Merchant merchant;
```

This is not terribly elegant, and I am at a loss how to replicate this for insert or update operations. One option is obviously to have separate DTOs and then recreate the relationships in my application, but the amount of overhead eats up the benefit of using JPA in the first place.

I realize HATEOAS, at least in theory, should solve this problem. However, it seems to me that this significantly raises the bar for implementing clients. It does not appear to be viable in some of my use cases.

So how do others solve this serialization / deserialization issue ?